# String memory not released at the end of a method?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, streamreader

I'm working on an xml to csv converter and I found out that my program may use too much memory from this part :

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(txtFileLocation))
{
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    s = s.Replace("&#xA;", "");
    xml.LoadXml(s);
}
```

The thing is, when the string variable gets set, my app takes up to 200mo memory then when I load it in my `XmlDocument`, it gets to 400 but it doesn't free the strings (or is it the `StreamReader`?) 200mo afterwards (except when I relaunch this method).

This much of memory comes from a 40mo source file, so I think it could get worse if I try to convert bigger files. Hence my question, (how) can I free this excess of memory usage?

Comment: For starters you shouldn't read all of a big file in memory but follow a more line by line approach (or some kind of blocksize)

Comment: What is mo? Should be Mb I think. It doesn't look too bad but instead of reading into a string and then converting to Xml (I suppose your xml.LoadXml does that) why not directly load Xml from the file? 
Second, you are not creating a string but 2 of them as almost the same copies in memory. Strings are immutable.

Comment: What is your intended operation once you read the file in memory. If you process the file one line at a time, there is no point of loading it entirely in memory first. For Xml use `XmlReader` for non-cached forward-only access to XML data. If the the string needs to be formatted/processed first before it can be read, try creating another file which keep the processed string. After that, use `XmlReader` on this processed file.

Comment: btw, you can replace this whole block of code with one-liner: xml.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(txtFileLocation).Replace("&#xA;", ""));

Comment: @Cetin it's MB (200Mo = 0.2 Go/GB is what I mean)

Comment: Its best not to assume, its better to go and read the ducmentation on how things work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: @TheGeneralI thought a variable should be garbage collected once it is out of scope. So basically, It won't be until necessary, right?

Comment: You are missing the root problem. You are creating 2 strings and also could load the XML directly. Then trust garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the memory is not being used by the stream reader or by the XML object you just loaded? Where is `xml` defined?

How much memory is too much? What is the best way to decide. .Net, on the whole, is "managed" and takes care of the memory management for you. Don't interfere or worry unless you actually have a problem. Just scope variables properly, call dispose when available. If you are using "unmanaged" resources then you have to implement `IDisposable` correctly (that doesn't apply here.)

If you are concerned the file will be really big, don't read it all at once, read it line by line. However, you are still loading this in into `xml` so another approach there would be required.

Comment: I inspected memory usage evolution via the task manager and ran my app line by line with VS, results: at start 30MB ram, when assigning sr.ReadAll() 200+MB a,d when loaded into my XmlDocument 400+MB ram usage (other checks led to the same results)
I don't know how much is too much but I just guessed if I needed to convert huge files this could potentially be a problem
I will try that block by block reading, that should do it anyway.

Comment: He at least creating 2 strings unnecessarily, when 1 (or 0 with direct loading of xml) might do. It is the root of the problem.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Loading it with a one liner like xml.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(txtFileLocation).Replace("&#xA;", "")); as mentioned by rs232 doesn't change the problem if it is what you mean.

Comment: Nope that is not what I meant. What does your xml.LoadXml() do? It should be doing some kind of XML reading. Many ready methods can directly use a file on disk to do without first reading into an intermediate string. Also, I would repeat you are creating 2 strings in memory. s = s.Something() doesn't simply replace string s in memory but creates a new one. Here you may not notice its side affects from memory wasting to speed but if you happen to repeat such operations it would also be really slow.

Comment: Wouldn't it mean that I would have to call the Replace(or equivalent) eveytime I read through the xmlDocument to check for invalid characters (so multiple calls instead of a single one here)?